# Cracking RSA keys, only given N and e

Tags: privacy, key-management, rsa, key

Is it possible to crack RSA keys when only given `N` and `e`? If so, is there a limit to how long `N` or `e` can be? How do you go about doing that?

In the specific scenario I'm researching, `N` is about 150 digits and `e` is about 5 digits. I also have `C`, but not `M`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the prime factors are p and q, but how do you even factor a 150 digit number. Is there another way?

Comment: @Arin Did you ever consider merging both of your accounts? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 512-bit key has about 154 decimal digits, so that should be the size you're facing. This should cost less than $100 to factor.

> The Factoring as a Service project is designed to allow anyone to factor 512-bit integers in as little as four hours using the Amazon EC2 platform for less than $100, with minimal setup.

See [Is 512-bit RSA still safe for signature generation?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/5942/180) for helpful links including how-tos and readily made scripts for running factoring on AWS.

There is also a good chance that the programmer messed up something, for example by using textbook RSA or providing a decryption oracle (if you have access to a server which can decrypt messages). But I'd only invest time in this if you either have the source code (so you can see which mistakes they made at a glance) or if it's a CTF (where you might be expected to exploit such a mistake).

Comment: What does the abbreviation CTF stand for?

Comment: @MartinBonner Capture-the-Flag, i.e.a puzzle designed to be solvable, not a real world problem. They generally contain a deliberate design flaw you're meant to exploit.